# Android Pop-up Window not displaying contents

Tags: android, layout, view, popup

I am trying to have a pop up window display results in a table after selecting certain things.  Below is my .xml of my popup window and the code I'm using to try to pull it up.  The problem is that when it pops up, it is only displaying a black box, not the rest of the contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/outerwindow"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="80dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#000000"
android:baselineAligned="true"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/insert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="@string/insert" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/window"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/material"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/back_arraw"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert" />

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/pRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#3b7fcc"
                android:baselineAligned="true" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/p0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/p"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/mRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffff57"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/m0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/m"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/kRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#cc3333"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/k0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/k"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/nRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#356638"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/n0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/n"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/sRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ff8936"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/s0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/s"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/hRow0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#898989"
                android:baselineAligned="false" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/h0"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/h"
                    android:textColor="#b0b0b0"
                    android:textSize="27dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="6" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/pRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#3b7fcc"
                        android:baselineAligned="true" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/p3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/mRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ffff57"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/m3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/kRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#cc3333"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/k3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/nRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#356638"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/n3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/sRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ff8936"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/s3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/hRow3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#898989"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/h3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="6" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/pRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#3b7fcc"
                        android:baselineAligned="true" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/p2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/space"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:baselineAligned="true" />

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/mRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ffff57"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/m2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/kRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#cc3333"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/k2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/nRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#356638"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/n2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/sRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ff8936"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/s2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/hRow2"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#898989"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/h2"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="6" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/pRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#3b7fcc"
                        android:baselineAligned="true" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/p1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/mRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ffff57"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/m1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/kRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#cc3333"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/k1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/nRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#356638"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/n1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/sRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#ff8936"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/s1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/hRow1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#898989"
                        android:baselineAligned="false" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/h1"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="17dp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

code in my main:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.outerwindow));
    popup = new PopupWindow(popView,100,100, true);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

later I use this command to bring it up

```
popup.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.primary), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

Obviously my main screen's ID is called primary, and when the the pop up comes up, its just a black square in the center of the screen (because I used black to see it actually pop up) and clicking outside of it makes it go away.  This is becoming a very annoying problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be you are using the incorrect context? Are you sure the getSystemService line is correct?

Comment: Not sure if it is exactly right, but this is the example they had in every example code I saw so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... So as you can see above my window was only 100x100...  That's why the content was blank... I was only showing the first 100x100 lol. Sorry all for being dumb.  Took me a good few hours to realize this.